# How to populate an interdependent select menu initially?

Tags: jquery

I have created two select menus that are dynamically populated using jquery:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  CateTypes();


  function CateTypes() {

    var cateAndTypes = {
      'Select': ['Select a Category first...'],
      'Colors': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Orange', 'Purple', 'Yellow'],
      'Shapes': ['Circle', 'Square', 'Triangle', 'Rectangle', 'Octagon'],
      'Sizes': ['Huge', 'Big', 'Small', 'Tiny'],
    };

    //populate Category
    $.each(cateAndTypes, function(c, t) {
      $('#category').append('<option value=' + c + '>' + c + '</option>');
    });

    //populate Type
    $('#category').on("change", function() {
      var $Types = $('#type');
      $Types.html("");
      var Types = cateAndTypes[$(this).val()];
      $.each(Types, function(c, t) {
        $Types.append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
      });
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <label>First, select a Category:</label>
  <br>
  <select id="category"></select>
</p>

<p>
  <label>Then, select a Type:</label>
  <br>
  <select id="type"></select>
</p>
```

My question is how do to get the #Type menu to populate using the initially selected option in the #Category menu upon loading.

Comment: relevance to php and mysql is? Edit: Those have been removed. You can put them back in once you've established relevance to the question.

Comment: Oh sorry. The initially selected option would be determined based on data retrieved from a MySQL database using PHP. But I decided to leave that part out at the last minute since I felt it wasn't really relevant to the actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger change event after the #category select is created, using `trigger('change')`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  CateTypes();
  function CateTypes() {
    var cateAndTypes = {
      'Select': ['Select a Category first...'],
      'Colors': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Orange', 'Purple', 'Yellow'],
      'Shapes': ['Circle', 'Square', 'Triangle', 'Rectangle', 'Octagon'],
      'Sizes': ['Huge', 'Big', 'Small', 'Tiny'],
    };

    //populate Category
    $.each(cateAndTypes, function(c, t) {
      $('#category').append('<option value=' + c + '>' + c + '</option>');
    });
    $('#category').prop('selectedIndex', 2);
    //populate Type
    $('#category').on("change", function() {
      var $Types = $('#type');
      $Types.html("");
      var Types = cateAndTypes[$(this).val()];
      $.each(Types, function(c, t) {
        $Types.append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
      });
    }).trigger('change');
//-----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label>First, select a Category:</label>
  <br>
  <select id="category"></select>
</p>

<p>
  <label>Then, select a Type:</label>
  <br>
  <select id="type"></select>
</p>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! For my own edification, if you've the time, can you explain why the .trigger() was needed?

Comment: @DannyLouis there are two was you can accomplish this. Either you can make a function with the `change` function body, and call that on change and load like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/m0czgqbr/), or you can just simply set the value on the `select#category` and  trigger a change event  on that so that our change callback function is executed.

Comment: Wow. Simple enough. Thanks again.

Comment: Final question: What if _(not really a hypothetical since it is exactly what I'm looking to do, but... )_ I wanted both the category _and_ type to be preselected based on predetermined values - i.e. values from text fields `#currentCate` and `#currentType`, respectively? _(These fields would get their values from a database, which I can easily handle. )_